# How to create Mysql Replication on mysql 5.5 master-slave

Tags: mysql-5.5

**Guyz please tell me how to replicate master-slave in mysql 5.5**

Answer (score 0):

maybe, you have to look over the documentation ?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html